# Indecomposable representations and purely inseparable extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and consider the extension $k(x)/k$ where $x^p\in k$ but $x$ does not. Consider a $k$-algebra $A$ (non commutative) and an $A\otimes_kk(x)$-module $M$, that is finite dimensional. If $M$ is indecomposable and not defined over $k$ (i.e. there does not exist an $A$-module $N$ such that $M=N\otimes_kk(x)$ is it true that $M$ is still indecomposable, when viewed as an $A$-module?

This question arised when considering the case of the map $k(x)\to k(x)$ given by multiplication by $x$. We may view this as a module under $k[T]$. If you want, assume that $A$ is finite dimensional (even if the original case would not really be covered).

Comment: @DavidHill I am not sure I understand, I tried with $A=M_2(k)$ ($A$ is over $k$) in many cases and my claim always seems to hold. Of course, there are way more $A$-modules than I can check by hand. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of $A=M_2(k)$. But, in that case, both $A$ and $A\otimes_k k(x)\cong M_2(k(x))$ are simple, so every indecomposable (= irreducible) module has the form $N\otimes k(x)$.

Comment: Exactly, so my claim holds, because my hypothesis is that $M$ is not defined over $k$.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an algebra $A$ and a module $M$ that does satisfy your hypotheses?

Comment: Take $A=k[u]$ the polynomial algebra in one variable. As $A_{k(x)}$ module take $M=k(x)$ (one dimensional $k(x)$-vector space) and let $u$ act on $M$ by multiplication by $x$. $M$ does not come from $k$, otherwise it would be multiplication by a scalar of $k$, and my claim holds, since the restriction of $M$ to $k$ (i.e. $M$ viewed as an $A$-module over $k$) can be put in a rational canonical form.

Comment: One of your hypotheses is that $A$ is non-commutative.

Comment: That was just to make clear that I wasn't interseted only in commutative algebras. Take $A=k\{u,v\}$ the free algebra on two generators, $M$ as before, and let $u$ act on $M$ as before and $v$ act trivially

Comment: @DavidHill is my formulation still not convincing/wrong?